# How do I connect to Cygwin/X via Go?

Tags: go, cygwin, xorg

I am using BurntSushi/xgbutil library which I have gotten to work on Linux. Now I am trying to get it to create a window on my Win7 running cygwin with xorg-server installed.

I'm not sure what I need to do to initialize the display, if anything.

My Go code looks like this:

```
X, err := xgbutil.NewConnDisplay(displayname)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

When `displayname = ":0"` I get `cannot connect to :0: dial unix /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: socket: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.`

When `displayname = "localhost:0"` I get `cannot connect to localhost:0: dial tcp [::1]:6000: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I'm not sure whether my problem is the displayname I'm using or if there is something I need to do in cygwin to make it work?

I *have* started xwin by using the xlaunch utility and an empty window sits on my desktop and identifies itself as "Cygwin/x:0.0" in the title bar.

Comment: How did you start the application? How if you try `localhost:0.0` for displayname? Please make sure Cygwin/X already running properly, e.g. by starting any of X-application in Cygwin. Also, run the application from cygwin terminal. Don't forget to allow connection in Windows firewall setting (port 6000).

Comment: @putu, I start the app with `go start app.go` from a cygwin terminal. I've tried adding entries to Windows Firewall to allow port 6000 inbound and outbound. Using `localhost:0.0` produces very similar results as `localhost:0`

Comment: The second error message indicates that the connection being dropped/refused, possibly due to firewall, hostname is wrong, or service is not available. Maybe you can try to set the displayname to `":0.0"`, and before executing the application, type `export DISPLAY=:0.0` in the cygwin terminal.

Comment: To enable X server TCP connections you need to start it with `/usr/bin/startxwin -- -listen` . Otherwise they are disabled by default